# two or more dictionaries have same value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I dont know exactly if my idea is a good idea, so please if it is easier in another way I don't see tell me!

I have an array of values (strings), and want to hash them with different keylength.
So I want to have for example 10 dicts which take

```
1. dict --> hash = string[:-1]  
2. dict --> hash = string[:-2]  
...  
10.dict --> hash = string[:-10]
```

the values should be always the same, the complete string.

So, in my further program, I want to go through the dicts with different hash-lengths, beginning with `string[:-1]`, proceeding to `string[:-10]`.
If my code finds the wished solution (doesn't matter what or how), the value for ALL dicts should be deleted as well as the hash itself.

In my naive thinking, I would have to find my solution, and delete it then in all dicts, not nice for large amounts of data.

So, my idea is, why don't I make these dicts pointing on a kind of array, delete the entry out of the array, so the value doesn't exist anymore --> catch exception or whatever if the dictentry isn't there anymore
(further optimization by deleting the dict-keys if you occur to get this kind of exception)

.. I hope it is understandable what I want to do, any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Knowing what programming language you're talking about would help.

Comment: ahh dammit, I'm sorry :D
It's Python2.7 I'm working with

Comment: You should use a different data structure.  Look up "trie" for example.